# Speeding up a very slow inner join query in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run the following SQL query with an index on the field 'source_key'.  In MySQL it hangs with a status of 'Sending data' for a very long time.

```
UPDATE clients_test c
INNER JOIN
(
select dob, last_name, soundex(first_name) as soundexfirstname, max(source_key) as keep
from clients_test
group by dob, last_name, soundex(first_name)
having count(*) = 2
) k
ON c.dob=k.dob AND c.last_name=k.last_name AND soundex(c.first_name)=k.soundexfirstname
SET duplicate_key = NULLIF(k.keep, c.source_key),
duplicate = (k.keep = c.source_key);
```

It is supposed to identify and remove duplicate records in a database table clients_test.  Is there any way to make this work faster or change the query to be more efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought would be to store the soundex() value in the database rather than recalculating it for every row.

And add a CHECK() constraint on the new soundex() column to make sure it stays in sync with the 'first_name' column.

Also, when you're trying to tune queries, EXPLAIN  is your friend.

Comment: Moving the soundex into a pre-calculated field definately sped this query up.  Still took a very long time on my low-powered cloud instance, but at least didn't hang for over a day!